# Angular http Post and Promise

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4 app which contains a button. On click of the button I do a http Post and insert an entry into a table. I then return the rowID for that newly inserted row in the response of the original http Post. I then want to consume this rowID and set it to a variable which exists at the same portion of the code where the http Post is performed. Problem is that variable never gets the value and I'm thinking it's related to the post returning a promise and the rest of the code executing prior to the promise being resolved. Is there an alternative to promise where I can extract the return value, or indeed a way to make it work ?

I'm new to Angular so still finding my feet somewhat.

Comment: You NEED to understand asynchronism (i.e. promises and observables). There is no way around them. Post your code, instead of vaguely describing it.

Comment: Could you provide us with some code examples. Did you try to subscribe on your http.post request and see what do you get as the response?

Comment: please, post your code here